# Clue for solving problem about Coupling of Random Variables.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, coupling

Just have been trying to approach this problem from Resnick's book on probability but have got no clue so far.

The problem is like this:

We are giving two random variables X, Y on the same space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B})$, and we are asked to show: $\sup_{A \in \mathcal{B} } | P[X\in A] - P[Y\in A] | \leq P[X \neq Y] $.

What I have thought:

1. My intuition is that maybe X and Y have the same distribution, although I don't see how the distribution of the two RVs plays a role here.
2. For the RHS I can say that  if we set $P[X \neq Y]  = \epsilon$, and we can check that the LHS $< \epsilon$ we may be able to get this done.
3. I realized that, if X, Y are random variables, then both satisfy the mapping:

$ X:(\Omega, \mathcal{B}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) $

Then, $A \in  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, so I'm confused why the problem states that $A \in  \mathcal{B}$.

Any solid hint please?

Comment: You want to fix $A \in \mathcal{B}$ and then show $P[X \in A] \leq P[Y\in A] + P[X\neq Y]$, then a similar inequality. Can you show that?

Comment: PS:  No need to worry about distributions or $\epsilon$-thingys here.  The random variables $X, Y$ can have different distributions and can be dependent.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I kinda got the intuition of your hint, but stuck on how to implement it. Moreover, I'm still confused on why $A\in \mathcal{B}$? since I'm thinking of: $X^{-1}(A)= \{ \omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in A\}$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. I'm confused about measures in this space. Any help will be helpful. Thank you all.

Comment: You are right.  I stated you should fix "$A \in \mathcal{B}$" only because that was the notation in the sup inequality in your question.  But indeed the notation of the inequality of your question is not correct:  $A$ is a subset of the reals, not necessarily a subset of $\Omega$.  So indeed that should be changed to "fix $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$" (using that to denote the collection of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$).  Overall, you just want to show $|P[X \in A] - P[Y \in A]| \leq P[X \neq Y]$ for all measurable subsets $A$ of the reals.

Comment: Ok then, so there seems to be a typo in the book? or maybe this is regular notation since this may be obvious for experienced people?
Anyways, my guess is I can say, Let $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then, $P[X\in A] $ is an induced measure: So, I can assume we have a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$, so I can compute $P(X^{-1}(A))$?

Comment: Yes.  The book just had a minor typo/mistake.

Comment: Ok. That's fine. I'm glad I was not totally wrong, at least for that part.  Now, I'm gonna try to  do something. using your hint. Thanks.

Comment: Any other clue is still welcome !

Comment: What about the union bound?

Comment: Ok, I started by: 

$ | P [\omega: X(\omega) \in A]  -  P [\omega: Y(\omega) \in A] | \leq  | \sum P(\omega: X(\omega) \in A )  -  \sum P(\omega: Y(\omega) \in A ) |  \leq \epsilon $ 

Where last $\epsilon$ comes from $P[X\neq Y]$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.   The sample space is not necessarily discrete, so summing is not appropriate here.  No need to use $\epsilon$ either. The approach of the first comment I gave is likely better.  Also note that $|x-y|\leq c$ if and only if $-c \leq x-y \leq c$, which is a useful fact for getting rid of pesky absolute value bars.  And, recall the union bound says $P[E \cup F] \leq P[E] + P[F]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that for any $A\in \mathcal B$, $$| P[X\in A] - P[Y\in A] | \leq P[X \neq Y]$$

By symmetry, it suffices to prove that $$P[X\in A] - P[Y\in A]  \leq P[X \neq Y]$$

which rewrites as $P[X\in A]   \leq P[Y\in A] + P[X \neq Y]$.

The last inequality follows from $$\begin{align}
P[X\in A] &= P[X\in A \;\cap\; X \neq Y] + P[X\in A \;\cap\; X = Y]\\
&= P[X\in A \;\cap\; X \neq Y] + P[Y\in A \;\cap\; X = Y]\\
&\leq P[ X \neq Y] + P[Y\in A ]
\end{align}$$

and we're done.

Comment: Yeah. I found out that there something called the coupling Lemma, well documented on books of Advanced Probability theory.  This answer seems to be the standard proof of such lemma.